# (CHAT ROOM) Usually only one address is allowed using a socket (protocol / network address / port)

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, port

I try to create a chat room in oop style, but socket don't work right.

ERROR:

> File "D:/Master/Chat/client_chat.py", line 10, in **init**
> self.client.bind(self.SERVER)
> OSError: [WinError 10048] Usually only one address is allowed using a socket (protocol / network address / port)

Server part:

```
import socket

class Server:
    def __init__(self):
        self.ADDR = "localhost"
        self.PORT = 5454
        self.SERVER = (self.ADDR, self.PORT)
        self.server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.server.bind(self.SERVER)
        self.server.listen()
        self.conn, self.addr = self.server.accept()
        self.message = self.conn.recv(64).decode('utf-8')
        print("[SERVER RUNNING]")

    def receive_message(self):
        return self.message


def main():
    print(Server())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Client part:

```
import socket


class Client:
    def __init__(self):
        self.ADDR = "localhost"
        self.PORT = 5454
        self.SERVER = (self.ADDR, self.PORT)
        self.client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.client.bind(self.SERVER)
        self.client.connect(self.SERVER)
        self.msg_inp = input().encode('utf-8')

    def send_message(self):
        return self.msg_inp


def main():
    print(Client())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Changing ports doesn't help!

Comment: `.bind()` is something you use on a server socket, not a client socket.  The actual server socket has already been bound to the port number you're trying to use.

Comment: It's alive! Thank you! I forgot about this line